# possible to change uitable cell rows without change page or runoithread

Tags: ios, uitableview, service, xamarin.ios, xamarin

i got a service code, and if i save the row should be change color, but doesnt change after i click. But if i change page with segue the next results are available, i used runoithread and reload table data but doesnt work. Any idea? my code ad bottom available

first image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHl9A.png
  and second image https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8jYj.png

here my getcell and save button at bottom

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
            {
                UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier);

                var cellStlye = UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle;
                if (cell == null) {
                    cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, cellIdentifier);
                }

                cell.TextLabel.Text = tableItemsX [indexPath.Row].MesajBasligi;
                cell.DetailTextLabel.Text = tableItemsX [indexPath.Row].CagriAcan;
                //  cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark;



                if (tableItemsX [indexPath.Row].Durum == true) {

                    cell.TextLabel.TextColor = UIColor.White;
                    cell.DetailTextLabel.TextColor = UIColor.White;
                    cell.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB (74, 160, 44);
                    cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark;
                    cell.TintColor = UIColor.FromRGB (43, 84, 126);

                } else {
                    cell.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB (43, 84, 126);
                    cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DetailButton;
                    cell.TextLabel.TextColor = UIColor.White;
                    cell.DetailTextLabel.TextColor = UIColor.White;
                    cell.TintColor = UIColor.FromRGB (74, 160, 44);

                }



                return cell;
            }



up.Process.Clicked += delegate {
                    new System.Threading.Thread (new System.Threading.ThreadStart (() => {
                        InvokeOnMainThread (() => {

                            bool state;

                            if (up.durumT.On)
                                state = true;
                            else
                                state = false;


                            var responseX = up.client.Post (new RequestUpdate {

                                Durum = state,

                                Gorulme = true,
                                TamamlanmaVakti = DateTime.Now,
                                YapilanIs = up.pesrsonelRaporu.Text,
                                CagriIlgilenen = up.sicil,
                                Id = conv

                            });



                            up.RequestListTable.ReloadData ();
                        });
                    })).Start ();

                };
```

Comment: Please write the question in a lil bit of understanding way, i don't understand what your question is and what you exactly want in your app.

Comment: i can't add image because of population, if you can check 2 images you can understand i suppose. actually i need refresh tableview

Comment: Where is the code that modifies `tableItemsX [indexPath.Row].Durum` ?

Comment: i fixed with {
   await LoadEntriesAsync ();
   RefreshControl.EndRefreshing ();
  }
but now table remembers old row datas? first ok but if i choose again another row, starats again first choiced is it a bug?